# On the operator norm

Tags: matrices, optimization, matrix-norms

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix. We want to calculate
>
> $$\|A\|^2 = \max_{v \in \mathbb{R}^n, \, |v|^2 =1} |Av|^2$$
>
> a) Show that the attempted problem has a solution.
>
> b) If $f(v) = |Av|^2$ and $h(v) = |v|^2$, what are the gradients of $f$ and $h$?
>
> c) The square root of the value of the optimisation $\|A\|$ is called the operator norm. What would be the operator norm if $A$ is symmetric?

I don't actually know where to start as I am not sure exactly what I am calculating. Any start off hints would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

a) The set $\mathbb{S}^n = :\{v \ | \ |v|^2 = 1\}$ is compact and matrix multiplication is continuous so the map
$$f = h\circ T_A  : \mathbb{S}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}^n$$
$$v \mapsto |Av|^2$$
where $h(v) = |v|^2$ must attain a maximum.

b) This is just chain rule
$$\nabla h = \nabla (v\cdot v) = 2 (\nabla v) v = 2 Iv = 2v $$
$$\nabla f = 2\nabla (Av)^T(Av) = 2A^TA v $$ 
see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_calculus)

c) If $A$ is symmetric you will have a full set of orthogonal eigenvectors, so consider what happens to those in regards to their corresponding eigenvalues. You can show that $A$ and $A^2$ will have the same eigenvalues.